# SQL Server and LINQ in ASP.NET Core - sequence

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a problem with this SQL. Maybe I am doing something wrong? I don't have a lot of experience.

When I try to create a new ticket on my web application, I get this:

[image: SqlException]

In my `TicketsController` in `Create[HttpPost]` it's crashing on the line `SaveChangesAsync`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(TicketCreateEditViewModel ticketModel)
{
        var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();

        var ticket = ticketModel.Ticket;
        ticket.ProductId = ticketModel.ProductId;
        ticket.Product = await _context.Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProductId == ticket.ProductId);
        ticket.StatusId = 1;
        ticket.Status = await _context.Statuses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.StatusId == 1);
        ticket.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        ticket.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
        ticket.PriorityId = 1;
        ticket.Priority = await _context.Priorities.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.PriorityId == 1);
        ticket.OwnerId = user.Id;
        ticket.Owner = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == ticket.OwnerId);

        {
            List<FileDetail> fileDetails = await FileUploadHelperExtensions.UploadFileAsync(_hostingEnvironment,
                _context,
                ticket.TicketId,
                Request.Form.Files);
            ticket.FileDetails = fileDetails;
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Owner");
            _context.Tickets.Add(ticket);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View(ticketModel);
}
```

Maybe new update in Visual Studio 2017 made this problem ?

Comment: Looks like the call to `ticketModel.ProductId` is returning an invalid `ProductId` because the call to save the ticket is failing due to the Foreign Key Constraint on ProductId. Put a break point and make sure the ProductId is valid.

Comment: The error is saying you are trying to insert a ticket with a ProductId that doesn't exist in the Products table, maybe you need to do some validation on your model before inserting?  Also you don't need to set the navigation properties on the ticket (Product/Priority/Owner)

Comment: So I dont have to in my Ticket Model doing something like this:
public int ProductId {get;set;}
public Product Product {get;set;}
?

Comment: Having those properties in the Ticket Model are fine, but if you set ticket.Product before trying to insert the ticket then it will try to insert the product as well and you'll have an all new problem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Just check if `ticketModel.ProductId` exists in the database.  My bet is that it's `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label asp-for="Ticket.Product"></label>
            <select asp-for="Ticket.ProductId" asp-items="Model.Products" class="custom-select"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Ticket.Product" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

In my view I have this. And I figured out that ticketModel doesn't contain my productId through my view.